# Reset upstream proxy header

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Given the below configuration:

```
proxy_set_header foo "bar";
proxy_set_header foo "baz";
```

Upstream is getting the below header:

```
foo: "bar, baz"
```

Is it possible to "unset" a header, so in this case upstream gets:

```
foo: "baz"
```

I am applying this configuration through a template engine (ingress-nginx for Kubernetes), so I cannot remove the first `proxy_set_header`.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want replace the header ? The `more_set_headers` might be helpful.

- examples:
  https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_set_headers

Comment: This will not work as I need to override headers forwarded to upstream, not response headers.